# How to group tools within a Python toolbox in ArcMap 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7, python-toolbox

I have created a simple Python toolbox at work for use in ArcMap 10.2. It is used by multiple members of staff so I'm hoping to make it as simple to use as possible. It currently only contains two scripts but I have others that I plan to add in the future. I am currently using the line below to load the two tools on startup, and whilst this is okay with only two scripts, it may become untidy as I add more.

`self.tools = [opentemplatecsv, batchcsvtopdf]`

Ideally it would be best to have one toolbox (i.e. "Dave's Tools") containing several sub-groups (e.g. "Mapping tools", "Modelling tools", "Hydrology tools"), each containing the appropriate scripts I've written.

Is there a way to place tools into sub-groups under the main toolbox, or is it best to simply add a few letters to the beginning of the scripts' names to alphabetically sort them?

i.e.

MAP - tool #1

MAP - tool #2

MOD - tool #3

HYD - tool #4

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Set the `category` attribute on your tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Defining_a_tool_in_a_Python_toolbox/001500000024000000/).

```
class MyTool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "This Particular Tool"
        self.description = "This tool"
        self.category = "This tool's grouping"
```